# How to close a Visual Studio tool window (not a document tab) using a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: visual-studio

As the title suggests, I would like to close a Visual Studio tool window (not a document tab) using a keyboard shortcut. Is that possible?

Comment: Toolbox? To close I don't know but to open it's `Ctrl + W, X`

Comment: Is it a window you are closing or are you talking about the toolbox pane?  Because if it't just a window you're talking about, alt-f4 will close the current window.

Comment: I'm talking about tool windows like, "Solution Explorer", "Server Explorer", "Pending Checkins".

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Shift + Esc seems to work

Comment: Thank you Gishu. I should have looked better under "Options > Environment > Keyboard" :)

Comment: @ Georges - I am guilty of that myself :) I knew it had something to do with the escape key... then I hopped onto google.

Comment: I've looked all my life for the shortcut. Now that the last piece of the puzzle has been laid I can finally throw away my mouse.

Comment: I find it odd that Ctrl+F4 still closes the active document even when the tool window has keyboard focus. Either way, you saved me some time, thanks!

Comment: Magic! Been trying to figure out how to close package manager console with keyboard. Don't want it docked and have keys mapped to open it but closing with the keyboard it was eluding me. I suppose Shift-Esc is some long defined but less known feature of toolbox windows in Windows itself.